# Syntax error when running a very simple shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I'm gettins this error when running a little script about rock, paper and scissors. Here is my code, and it fails on the second elif statement, could you figure out why??

```
function compare () {
    if [ "$userChoice" == "$computerChoice" ]
       then echo "Empate!"
    elif [ "$userChoice" == "piedra" ]
        if [ "$computerChoice" == "tijeras" ]
            then echo "La piedra gana"
        else
            echo "El papel gana"
        fi
    elif [ "$userChoice" == "papel" ]
        if [ "$computerChoice" == "piedra" ]
            then echo "El papel gana"
        else
            echo "Las tijeras ganan"
        fi
    fi
}
compare $userChoice $computerChoice
```

The error message is:

```
myscript: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
myscript: line 10: `    elif [ "$userChoice" == "papel" ]'
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! +1 for including enough code to diagnose the problem! I added the error message to make it even easier to diagnose. Consider installing/using [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net): for your snippet it points to the problem and says "Did you forget the 'then' for this 'elif'?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot a couple "then" statements. Good way to always remember is to add the "then" statement to the same line as the "if". Example is below.

```
function compare () {
if [ "$userChoice" == "$computerChoice" ] ; then
  echo "Empate!"
elif [ "$userChoice" == "piedra" ] ; then
  if [ "$computerChoice" == "tijeras" ] ; then
     echo "La piedra gana"
  else
     echo "El papel gana"
  fi
elif [ "$userChoice" == "papel" ] ; then
  if [ "$computerChoice" == "piedra" ] ; then
     echo "El papel gana"
  else
      echo "Las tijeras ganan"
  fi
fi
}
compare $userChoice $computerChoice
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `then` after the elif as well.